# Anonymous generic parameter in recursive record definition

Tags: f#

I'm building a HFSM and using a record to keep track of the state:

```
type State<'a> =
    {
        CurrentNodeId : int
        Data : 'a
    }
```

When the current node has another HFSM as part of it, I need to keep track of that state as well. So I wanted to do something like this

```
type State<'a> =
    {
        CurrentNodeId : int
        Data : 'a
        SubState : State<_> list
    }
```

Because I don't really care what type the `SubState list` is, but it errors out with:

> Anonymous type variables are not permitted in this declaration

Is there a different, more idiomatic F# way to do this or will I have to come with a different solution?

Comment: it's not a F# problem - it's a problem with your definition - you have to specify the type there! So if it has type 'a or some common subtype use it - if not you must either remove the `Data` part and the generics completely, use something like an interface for `State` without the data-part  or move towards `obj` :(

Comment: just to make this clear: usually you don't really need the data part as you can have a mapping from your NodeId to data, and if you think about it you all this data should really be of the same type

Comment: All I care about is that all substate elements have the same type. But I do not know the type at compile time. I guess it's impossible to define this in F# type system.

Comment: Could you make `SubState` be of type `'b`?

Comment: yes if all *Substates* have the same type you could go `type State<'base,'sub> = { Data : 'base; ... SubState : State<'sub,'sub> }` - if you don't know it than `'sub ~ obj` ofc.

Comment: btw: why don't you know it at compile time? (you cannot express what you don't know - that's true for all type systems)

Comment: The HFMS will be build dynamically from a definition, so the actual type only becomes known at runtime. In any case, using `type State<'base,'sub>` won't work because there can be an arbitrary depth of substates, all with different types.

Comment: Why not `State<_> seq`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tomas is right that there's no super-clean way to do this in F#, but I think it's possible to do it a bit more nicely than his approach.  The basic idea is that you want a type like this:

```
type State<'a> = {
    CurrentNodeId : int
    Data : 'a
    SubState : ∃'x. State<'x> list
}
```

except that F# doesn't directly support existential types.  It turns out that there's a fairly standard way to encode existential types in terms of universal types (which F# does support):

```
∃'x.T<'x> ≡ ∀'z.(∀'x.T<'x> -> 'z) -> 'z
```

Unfortunately, this actually requires two extra types because each universal quantification is encoded as a single generic method on a unique type:

```
type State<'a> = {
    CurrentNodeId : int
    Data : 'a
    SubStates : SomeStateList
}
and SomeStateList =
    abstract Apply : StateListApplication<'z> -> 'z
and StateListApplication<'z> =
    abstract Apply : State<'x> list -> 'z
```

Note that there's an extra type here compared to Tomas's solution, but the benefit is that you don't have to pick a single return type for all *uses* of a particular `State` (Tomas's encoding basically inlines the `SomeStateList` type into `State` and lifts the type parameter `'z` to the `State` type in the process).

Now we want to be able to pack up a list of states of some arbitrary type as a `SomeStateList`:

```
let pack states = { new SomeStateList with member __.Apply a = a.Apply states }
```

and we can demonstrate how to use these types with the analogous definition to Tomas's recursive `depth` function.  We wish we could just write

```
let rec depth = 1 + s.SubStates |> List.map depth |> List.fold max 0
```

But we need to add some extra syntax to take care of creating and applying our generic types (though hopefully the core logic is still apparent if you squint):

```
// Full type annotation necessary here to get inner use to typecheck
let rec depth<'a> (s:State<'a>) : int = 
    1 + s.SubStates.Apply { 
        new StateListApplication<_> with 
            member __.Apply l = l |> List.map depth |> List.fold max 0 
}
```

And creating a graph and applying the function is pretty clean:

```
depth {
    CurrentNodeId = 1
    Data = "test"
    SubStates = pack [{ CurrentNodeId = 2
                        Data = 1uy
                        SubStates = pack []}]
}
```

Comment: Nice! Yeah, I was just lazy with the return type. Although, I'm not sure what I was doing wrong when defining the recursive `depth` function - no matter what I tried, it was always complaining (so I thought it never lets you call the function recursively with different type argument... is that why you need `let rec depth<'a>` here?)

Comment: @TomasPetricek - Yeah, the type parameter needs to be explicit in the definition and the argument and return types need to be fully annotated (and if you don't do all of that, the error messages aren't super helpful...).

Comment: I never got around to implement your solution, but have since revisited it, and will accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't really have a good solution in F#. In practice, I would probably just keep the state as `obj` and unbox it to the type I'm expecting there, or I would store the state using a simple discriminated union that captures the possible cases.

There is a very complex way to do this, which might be encoding what you want, but will make your code look pretty horrible (I played with this and I don't think I can make it nice). The idea is to store an *interface* with a single `Invoke` method that is generic and will be called with the type parameter of the type stored in the children:

```
type InvokeWithState<'R> =
  abstract Invoke<'T> : State<'T, 'R> list -> 'R

and State<'T, 'R> =
  { CurrentNodeId : int
    Data : 'T
    SubStates : InvokeWithState<'R> -> 'R }
```

So, if you want to do some operation over `State<'T, 'R>` you can write `InvokeWithState<'R>` interface that does something with the children. A simple HFSM with root state containing string and child state containing numbers looks like this:

```
let hfsm = 
  { CurrentNodeId = 1
    Data = "root"
    SubStates = fun op ->
      op.Invoke
        [ { CurrentNodeId = 2 
            Data = 42
            SubStates = fun op -> op.Invoke [] } ] }
```

The idea is that `SubStates` function will call the `Invoke` operation and give it  values of `State<int, 'R>` (the `'R` type represents result of the operation that we are running).

Working with these things is also pretty ugly - because ordinary F# recursive functions cannot call themselves with another type parameter as argument. But you can write something like this (to count the depth of the FSM):

```
type HfsmOp<'R> =
  abstract Invoke<'T> : State<'T,'R> -> 'R

let rec depth =
  { new HfsmOp<int> with
      member x.Invoke(state) =
        let childDepth = 
          { new InvokeWithState<int> with
              member x.Invoke<'T>(states:State<'T, int> list) : int = 
                if List.isEmpty states then 0
                else states |> List.map (fun s -> depth.Invoke<'T> s) |> List.max }
          |> state.SubStates 
        childDepth + 1}

depth.Invoke hfsm
```

This might be doing what you want (in general), but it looks horrible and I would not really recommend doing this. We use similar trick in [one place in Deedle](https://github.com/BlueMountainCapital/Deedle/blob/1c3d73cc02b16849be765b4c327874ec35e5d327/src/Deedle/Vectors/Vector.fs#L68) but that's very limited in scope and so it does not make the entire code base ugly. In most cases though, I'd go with a discriminated union or `obj`.

Comment: I think it's possible to do slightly better - see my answer.  Also, normal `let`-bound functions *can* use polymorphic recursion (recursive calls at a type different from the outer call) - you just need to explicitly add generic type parameters and fully annotate the definition.